# How deactivate some functions in VADER (sentiment analysis library) for example: deactivate removing punctuations

Tags: python-3.x, vader

How deactivate some functions in VADER (sentiment analysis library) for example: deactivate removing punctuations or deactivate stops words and lemmatising and so on?

https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment

Because I do not know how edit the code and import the code after deactivate these functions

Answer (score 0):

Vader is an open source library. You can simply fork the repository(simple google would help) of the code and comment the function you want to deactivate and comment its usages.

Warning: you should be aware of what you're doing, before commenting a function you need to understand how the flow of the whole library works.